# Java ArrayList Out of Bounds Exeption

Tags: java, arraylist, blackjack

I am making a blackjack game (NON GUI) and I will write algorithms to decide whether to receive another card, how much to bet, etc. I am receiving an out of bounds error on the ArrayList when I am adding values. Thank you for your help.

```
    package idk;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Something {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Something something = new Something();
    ArrayList<Integer> place=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        place.add(2);
    }
    for(i=4; i<8; i++)
    {
        place.add(3);
    }
    for(i=8; i<12; i++)
    {
        place.add(4);
    }
    for(i=12; i<16; i++)
    {
        place.add(5);
    }
    for(i=16; i<20; i++)
    {
        place.add(6);
    }
    for(i=20; i<24; i++)
    {
        place.add(7);
    }
    for(i=24; i<28; i++)
    {
        place.add(8);
    }
    for(i=28; i<32; i++)
    {
        place.add(9);
    }
    for(i=32; i<48; i++)
    {
        place.add(10);
    }
    for(i=48; i<52; i++)
    {
        place.add(11);
    }
    for(i=0; i<52; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(place.get(i));
    }
    int[] dealer;
    dealer = new int[28];
    for(int w=0; w<2; w++)
    {
     int min = 0;
        int max = 52;
       int range = (max - min);

        int random = new Random().nextInt(range + 1) + min;
       int card = place.get(random);
       dealer[i]=card;
       place.remove(random);
       if(i==1)
       {
           System.out.println("The dealer's face up card is " + card);
       }

    }







}
```

}

Comment: Read the exception. Go to the line it tells you has a problem. Figure how how the value got to be out of bounds. Fix. Are you expecting us to build your code and do all that for you?

Comment: Thanks, I have a lot more coding and developing to do so the algorithms will make the decisions for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line `dealer[i]=card;`

Check the value of `i`, it is greater than the declared size of `dealer[]`.

After the last `for` loop with `i`, the value of `i` will be 52, and `dealer[]` size is 28.

Comment: Also, `nextInt(range + 1)` should just be `range`, because 52 is already an exclusive upper bound. Finally, never make aces 11 in blackjack programs: it makes later code too complex. Make aces 1, then just add 10 to any hand less than 12 that contains at least once ace. Much simpler, more reliable code. And finally, you know you can nest loops, right?